# How to Display a PNG from drawable Folder?

Tags: android, png, drawable

I have been trying to display a PNG file in my activity with little success.

I have a file named `arrow.png` in my `res/drawable` folder and my code is as follows:

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
    }
}
```

Of all the guides/examples I've read, they all gave me the same instructions as what I've created above. But when I run this program, there's nothing that shows up (the TextView displays just fine – image is nonexistent). I'm pretty baffled as to why this is happening, as there are no error messages.

I've checked to see if the PNG file is corrupt, but that's also not the case. I've cleaned the project and restarted, but that still doesn't help. What am I missing/overlooking?

Comment: The meathod you have done to display png is correct....i think there is some problem in your png....can you show the png file or try some other png with same code.

Comment: could it be that the image is too large in dimensions? Not sure what happens if the space available is smaller than the image. See if anything changes if you remove the padding of the RelativeLayout. Or maybe the file is too large is filesize making it go out of memory, that sometimes too then just leaves out the image. Also, do you see the image in the XML graphical layout view in your IDE? It should show there also, seeing that you also put it as `android:src`

Comment: Thanks, Navjot Bedi and, more specifically, @IvoBeckers, you guys hit the nail square on the head with those suggestions. I made the PNG in Photoshop and then forgot to resize it. I readjusted it to 12.5% of its original size and now it displays just fine. If you write your comment out as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for seeing what I overlooked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image might be too large.

Comment: Can you provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new drawable resource folder and store in high density format.

Right click on res-> New -> Android Resource directory

[image]

You can select the density according to your image quality.

[image]